# How to get rid of a numerical index/key set in php array?

Tags: php

How to get rid of the numerical indexes in the following array:

```
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [ 2018:08:30-07:00:00 ] => 16.772925
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [ 2018:08:30-07:15:00 ] => 16.770355
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [ 2018:08:30-07:30:00 ] => 16.77907
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [ 2018:08:30-07:45:00 ] => 16.78735
            )
     )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [ 2018:08:30-07:00:00 ] => 16.772925
            )
    )
```

so that it looks like this:

```
 [0] => Array
 (
            [ 2018:08:30-07:00:00 ] => 16.772925
            [ 2018:08:30-07:15:00 ] => 16.770355
            [ 2018:08:30-07:30:00 ] => 16.77907
            [ 2018:08:30-07:45:00 ] => 16.78735
 )
 [1] => Array
 (
            [ 2018:08:30-07:00:00 ] => 16.772925
 )
```

My php code:

```
$time_to_priceee_1 = array();
$z_1 = 0;
foreach($pvt_1 as $pvtt_1)
{
    echo '1';
    $y_1 = 0;
    foreach($pvtt_1 as $pvttt_1 => $pvtttt_1)
    {
        $time_to_price_1[$z_1][$y_1] = $pvtttt_1['time'];
        $time_to_pricee_1[$z_1][$y_1] = $pvtttt_1['price'];
        $time_to_priceee_1[$z_1][$y_1] = array($pvtttt_1['time'] => $pvtttt_1['price']);
        $y_1 = $y_1 + 1;
    }

    $z_1 = $z_1 + 1;
}
```

The output of `$time_to_priceee_1` is the very first array that I posted. That's what I seem to get. Have tried `$time_to_priceee_1[$z_1]`, `$time_to_priceee_1`, `$time_to_priceee_1[]`, `$time_to_priceee_1[$z_1][$y_1] = array($pvtttt_1['time'], $pvtttt_1['price'])` but I think I'm trying the wrong areas.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, just worked it out. This is the code that works:

`$time_to_priceee_1[$z_1][$pvtttt_1['time']] = $pvtttt_1['price'];`\

Thanks anyway.